# Less than two, Plural or Singular

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

There **is/are** less than two samples.  (Discrete space)

(It is clear that for numbers like 3 or 4 the right word is "are" as we could have multiple samples, but using 2 we could only have either 0 or 1.)

Comment: realize that for '0' you would use "are", and whether or not your specific example can only contain discrete numbers is irrelevant, because generally "less than 2" can still be more than 1. You definitely use "are" here.

Comment: 'There are less/fewer than two samples' is what is used. Contrast 'There is less than two minutes to go', 'There is less than two thousand dollars to go' (with continuous or treated-as-continuous measures). Compare 'More than one passenger was hurt'.

Comment: There are ***fewer*** than two samples.

Comment: @Lambie The fewer than/less than debate is in flux. [Google 4-grams for fewer/less than two people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fewer+than+two+people%2Cless+than+two+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfewer%20than%20two%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%20two%20people%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfewer%20than%20two%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cless%20than%20two%20people%3B%2Cc0). Certainly 'That's one less problem' is idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Be that as it may, fewer samples sounds better than less samples. I don't know why you bother to tell me about it being in flux. Editors are not in flux about it.

Comment: @Lambie ELU isn't merely for editors or those they can mandate to: it's about generally accepted usages. And note that you've skewed this; 'There are less than two samples' is not comparable idiomaticity-wise to 'less samples'.

Comment: In my opinion "less than 2" is a really obscure way of saying "0 or 1" or "at most 1" and should be avoided unless there is a really specific reason such as "there are always 2 or more of A and less than 2 B"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The generally accepted usage in terms of publications etc. here is fewer not less. I really don't care what academics says about this.

Comment: @Lambie But Google ngrams don't sample academics.  And further real statistics: "fewer than two people" cf  "less than two people" in a raw Google search: ratio of hits about 9 : 34.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, Edwin, you win. Have it your way. Google dredges up all kinds of crap. It is not a equal opportunity discriminator.